# Can IntelliJ generate souce code when making Swing GUIs with Intellijs gui designer?

Tags: swing, user-interface, intellij-idea

I cant just add another dependency to the proeject - the IntelliJs "compile intellij form to java-source, or bytecode instrumentation".

I need the java source code to be generated when I use the Swing GUI designer in IntelliJ, not more xml forms.

The setting under "GUi Designer" is set to "Generate java code" but it still generates a .form with intellij-specific xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to generate and store GUI directly in Java source files only, there will be always a .form file with XML. You can control how compilation is perfomed, via source code generation (which then can be compiled with any compiler) or via bytecode instrumentation (if you need to compile with this setting externally, use the provided **javac2** Ant task that can compile .form files).

Comment: Can maven compile the xml form?

Comment: We don't support it officially, but you can find some workarounds at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-31368.